# Как записывать десятичные через запятую?

Tags: reactjs

Есть код, который переводит int в sting:

```
const sp = int => {
  int = int.toString();
  return int.split('').reverse().join('').match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join('.').split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Допустим:

```
int = 3300
(sp{int})
```

Вывод будет таким: "**3.300**", помогите, пожалуйста, доработать мой код, чтобы это работало примерно так:

```
Ввод:
int = 3300.4
{sp(int)}
Вывод:
3.300,4
```

Answer (score 3):

Для этого можно воспользоватся [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Например:

```js
const number = 3300.4

console.log(number.toLocaleString("en-US")) //3,300.4
```

Или как в вашем варианте требуется:

```js
const number = 3300.4

console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE')) //3.300,4
```

Больше ознакомится с опциями можно в [примерах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#example_using_locales) и [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) на MDN